# SFML C++11 Trying to call a function in an object which is in a vector

Tags: c++, function, c++11, vector, sfml

So I am trying to make a simple shooter but so far i had no luck. I want to spawn bullets when the user presses right shift. And the bullets should fire at the top of the screen. The bullets do spawn but they dont move.

I created a vector to hold the created bullets named "bullets". Then I used the update function in my core struct to detect RShift presses and push an instance of the Bullet object to the vector.

Later on in my main class I iterate the vector and draw the bullets. But when I try calling the function it doesnt work.

My Code so far:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>

const unsigned int ResX{480}, ResY{640};

struct Bullet {
    sf::CircleShape shape;

    Bullet(float sX, float sY, sf::Color color, float bullet_radius) {
        shape.setRadius(bullet_radius);
        shape.setOrigin(bullet_radius, bullet_radius);
        shape.setFillColor(color);
        shape.setPosition(sX, sY);
    }

    void update(float vel) {
        sf::Vector2f velocity;
        velocity.y = -abs(vel);
        shape.move(velocity);
    }
};

std::vector<Bullet> bullets;

struct Core {
    const float core_width{64}, core_height{48}, core_velocity{0.2};

    sf::RectangleShape shape;
    sf::Vector2f velocity;



    Core(float sX, float sY) {
        shape.setSize({core_width, core_height});
        shape.setPosition(sX, sY);
        shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
        shape.setOrigin(core_width/2, core_height/2);
    }

    void update() {

        if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left))
            velocity.x = -core_velocity;
        else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
            velocity.x = core_velocity;
        else
            velocity.x = 0;

        if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up))
            velocity.y = -core_velocity;
        else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down))
            velocity.y = core_velocity;
        else
            velocity.y = 0;

        shape.move(velocity);

        if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::RShift)) {
            Bullet b(shape.getPosition().x, shape.getPosition().y, sf::Color::Red, 5);
            bullets.push_back(b);
        }
    }
};



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(ResX, ResY), "Brick Breaker", sf::Style::None);

    Core core(ResX / 2, ResY /2 + 200);


    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed || sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Escape))
                window.close();
        }

        std::printf("VelocityX=%f, BulletVelocity=\n",core.velocity.x);

        window.clear();

        core.update();

        window.draw(core.shape);
        for(const auto& b : bullets)
            window.draw(b.shape);
        //this function is causing an error : method update could not be resolved!
            b.update();
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

btw i feel the need to say i am very very unexperienced with programming in c++ I am a complete beginner so any advice is welcome. srry 4 bad english. thanks!

EDIT: I figured it out thx! (The problem was that i missed the curly brackets:

```
    for(const auto& b : bullets)
        {
        window.draw(b.shape);
            //this function is causing an error : method update could not be resolved!
        b.update();
        }
```

But i have another question aswell! It would be awesome if one of you explained how the iterator functions and what purpose the auto& and const keywords serve here. Thanks again!

Comment: `Bullet::update` takes a `float` parameter, but you aren't passing it anything.

Comment: Can you define *doesn't work*?

Comment: And I think you can't call a non const function if you define your variable as const.

Comment: @acwaters the problem isn't with me passing no arguments to the function. The IDE says the function name isn't resolved. Basically the program cant find any update method within the b object instantiated there.

Comment: @NathanOliver doesn't work as in the instantiated bullet should move towards the top of the screen but it doesnt. And the core object (a rectangle) should be able to spawn more bullets that also move to the top of the screen. I hoped that running the update function in every iterated bullet object in the vector would help me with this but i cant call the function..

Comment: @JMA well found the iterator loop on the internet. I dont know what "const auto&" means in that line. I understand the "b : bullets" tho. So it would be awesome if you could explain the meaning of that

Comment: omg just kill me the problem was the syntax i forgot to add the curly brackets. sorry for wasting your guys' time. But i would be really happy if one of you could explain how the iterator works.